# Could using "a punto" in a phrase be redundant?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I'm not intending the general application of "a punto" but I think in the following phrase it is sort of redundant, isn't it?

> Ci volle un decennio perché riuscissero a portarla a punto in una versione che fosse più gradevole e meno “medicinale”.

Comment: Where does this sentence come from?

Comment: Looking at [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00001007.jpg), which maybe is the most complete dictionary of Italian language, the expression "portare a punto" doesn't appear. [Searching with Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22portare+a+punto%22) one finds some occurrences, but not many. So, as @DaG has said, it may be a (regional?) variant of "mettere a punto" (at least it's what seems to me reading some of the examples found with Google).

Comment: I think it's a slight variation of the already quoted expression _mettere a punto_. The expression _portarla_ (_bring it_) instead of metterla (_set it/get it_) implies **the process** of getting it to the final state _a punto_ (_on point/to spec_). I don't think it's a regionalism, just a way to intensify the idea that it wasn't in that state and they had to bring it there. It's a different point of view. If you _set it_, you start from the state it is, and go forward. If you _bring it_, you get it from the state it was, and get to the state it is now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an Italian native speaker this phrase sounds a little awkward to me because I would have written:

> ...perché riuscissero a **metterla** a punto in una versione...

In the other hand it clearly means something like *"optimise it"* up to a level that it could be safely and efficiently used for the task it is meant to. In English I would say *"fine tuning it"* but I'm not an English native speaker.

So in this sense I don't feel the expression is redundant. It's just awkward based on my use of Italian as a native speaker.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Benvenuto! Good answer; it would be even better with a reference from a dictionary for "mettere a punto", for instance item 10d of the [definition of `punto` on Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/punto2).